# Communication between models

Tags: qt, oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller, model

My program loads records (one per line) from file in raw format.

I have some Views for displaying this data in different ways:

- Byte View
- Decimal View (by doing some calculations with byte ranges)

Both Views must provide the ability for editing values.

Here is some code:

```
class Record
{
public:
  void setByte (int position, Byte byte);
  void setValue (ValueType type, Value value);

  Byte getByte (int position) const;
  Value getValue (ValueType type) const;

private:
  RawData data;
}
```

I'm loading records in

```
QVector<Record> records;
```

Byte View is a simple table with hex bytes (row - line number, column - byte position). Decimal View is a table too (row - line number, one column - value).

So,what's the best way to design Model(s) for my Views with the ability to communicate with each other (f.e. sending signals when a data was modified from one of the Views)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using Qt, it's usually best to subclass one of the Qt's own models. This way you'll get a lot of view widgets for free, and at the same time make your code more consistent by following the same standard as the rest of the toolkit you use. [Qt's documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference) have some  guidelines stating which methods/signals/slots you must implement.

Some classes to take a look at: [QAbstractItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#subclassing), [QAbstractTableModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html#subclassing) and [QAbstractListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html#subclassing)

For the view side, you should prefer to use widgets provided by Qt, and if necessary, implement a [delegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#details) to change it's appearance.

In your specific case, I'd subclass QAbstractTableModel, and wrap your records inside this class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i need more general solution, like UML sketch (i mean class diagramm) or smth like this.

Comment: @SandyEmerald Please update your question to reflect what you're really intending to so. Your proposed Record is even less general than Qt's models. You can very easily represent a tree of tables of records in a Qt model. So far I don't see why you'd need a "more general" solution. Is your data structure not representable by a tree?

Comment: @KubaOber the idea of the question is how to design my model(s) to communicate with each other when i was editing some value in any of my Views? I mean i have one data source (vector of my records) and different ways to change data (by editing hex or decimal values). So what my model(s) should exactly being?

Comment: My answer covers all you said. If you combine Qt views with delegates, you can display/edit data from Qt models in any way you need

Comment: @sandyEmerald Subclass `QAbstractItemModel` or, more easily `QAbstractListModel` or `QAbstractTableModel`. See [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html). Then implement your views so that they react appropriately to the model's signals, or reuse existing views such as `QTreeView` etc.

Comment: Okay, may be i need more time trying to implement it. Thanks for you help!